# Security audit for Token Distribution ICO

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

This is our MEG-Token-Distribution 1.0. We need a help from someone.
[Link for full code](https://github.com/eggith/MEG-Token-Distribution/blob/master/EggithCrowdsale.sol).

How we can make access for mint function (token owner is EggithCrowdsale)?

How we can change rate depend on msg.value (if > 20 ETH price another)?

```
contract EggithToken is MintableToken {
    string public constant name = "EggithToken";
    string public constant symbol = "MEG";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;
}

contract EggithCrowdsale is Crowdsale {
    function EggithCrowdsale(uint256 _startTime, uint256 _endTime, uint256 _rate, address _wallet)
         Crowdsale(_startTime, _endTime, _rate, _wallet)
    {
    }

    // creates the token to be sold. 
    // override this method to have crowdsale of a specific mintable token.
    function createTokenContract() internal returns (MintableToken) {
        return new EggithToken();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"How we can change rate depend on msg.value (if > 20 ETH price another)?"**

```
   uint public constant regularPrice = 100;
   uint public constant moreThan20EthContributionPrice = 75;

   function () payable { 
   //fallback function that is called when ETH is sent to contract

   ... some code ...

   uint price = calculatePrice();

   ... some code ...

    }

    function calculatePrice() internal constant returns (uint) {
        if (msg.value > 20 ether) return moreThan20EthContributionPrice;
        return regularPrice;
   }
```

Comment: Remember when executing the fallback method you only have 2300 gas available so all operations have to be less than this amount! See http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#fallback-function